# Between Two Date Condition in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have table called `Master` and i need all the possible records of all matching date as per user Input between `@FromDate` and `@Todate`....

**Master Table:**

```
ID    FromDate    ToDate 
1    18/03/2014   18/03/2014
2    01/03/2014   05/03/2014
3    06/03/2014   08/03/2014
```

**My Query:**

```
select ID 
from master M 
where M.FromDate between('10/03/2014') and ('17/03/2014') 
    or M.ToDate between ('10/03/2014') and ('17/03/2014')
```

**User Input:**

```
FromDate      ToDate
01/03/2014   06/03/2014
01/03/2014   31/03/2014
09/03/2014   09/03/2014
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2,3
1,2,3
No Records
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Got The Solution:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM master M 
WHERE ((M.FromDate BETWEEN '10/03/2014' AND '17/03/2014') 
     OR (M.ToDate BETWEEN '10/03/2014' AND '17/03/2014'))
```

parenthesis is Very Important in Sequel Server.....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select ID from master M where (M.FromDate>='10/03/2014' M.FromDate<'17/03/2014') or (M.ToDate>='10/03/2014' and M.ToDate<'17/03/2014');
```

Comment: No Condition is not correct, i need the solution for all the condition in a query...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put parenthesis... SQL will find it hard which condition is which...

```
SELECT ID 
FROM master M 
WHERE (M.FromDate BETWEEN '10/03/2014' AND '17/03/2014') 
OR (M.ToDate BETWEEN '10/03/2014' AND '17/03/2014')
```

Comment: No Condition is not correct, i need the solution for all the condition in a query...

Comment: Do you have your condition fields as date datatype?

Comment: actually i used Column has datetime datatype and also i have created user defined function for casting only dates and removing time part... so only condition is incorrect.....

Comment: Based on the result you want, I have tested this against an actual SQL database, it is correct. I have your sample data and all outputs the desired result.